# How to update params after navigating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react navigation stack which has two screens: Landing and PreLoginQuestion

**Landing.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Api from '../services/Api';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Landing extends Component {

preLoginDataURL = 'pre-login/data/get';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const response = await Api.getData(this.preLoginDataURL);
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

onNextStepsPress = () => {
    console.log('In next steps');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Question', {
        data: this.state.data
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Next Steps" onPress={this.onNextStepsPress} />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

**PreLoginQuestion.js**

```
export default class PreLoginQuestion extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navigation = this.props.navigation;
    this.data = this.navigation.state.params.data;
    console.log(this.data);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Pre login question Component</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

I am sending the data as a param from Landing component to the PreLoginQuestion component. At the starting it is null, but when it is retrieved from the api I want to get that updated value in the PreLoginQuestion component. So my question is, that how do I make a change to the already sent params so that I can get the changed value in the navigated screen (PreLoginQuestion) ?

I have tried `NavigationActions.setParams()` with dispatch but couldn't make it work.

I'm very new to react and react native so please forgive me if I'm not using the correct approach :D

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to render an `ActivityIndicator` component on your `Landing` component while you are making the networking request. Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Api from '../services/Api';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Landing extends Component {

preLoginDataURL = 'pre-login/data/get';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const response = await Api.getData(this.preLoginDataURL);
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

onNextStepsPress = () => {
    console.log('In next steps');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Question', {
        data: this.state.data
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.state.data ?
            <Button title="Next Steps" onPress={this.onNextStepsPress} /> :
            <ActivityIndicator/>}
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

And then, once you navigate to that `PreLoginQuestion`, you are guaranteed to have the data available. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello @luizParreira thanks for answering. But I don't want to show any kind of loader on the Landing page. I am trying this approach so that the request is sent before the user clicks the button. But if the response is not available even after navigating to PreLoginQuestion, then I'll show the loader inside that component.

Comment: @AkashNigam You could try and fetch the data on the `componentWillMount()` method instead 

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call api in PreLoginQuestion component(in componentDidMount )

Or use a state management thing (redux or mobx). When get response dispatch data than you can get data from reducer easily.